# php validation on form issues

Tags: php, html

Ive been working on this form validation all day and Im almost there but its just not right yet. I was told to use the example at w3schools and I did but it didnt work. I messed around with it for a while and now it does validate , but a few things are still messed up.  If there are more than 1 error it doesnt show up. Only the last one to occur shows up. Secondly I want it to show the errors by the inputs on the page. currently it goes a to blank page and just echos the error. I tried including them in the html of the form but its not working. the example i used is:

https://www.w3schools.com/php/showphp.asp?filename=demo_form_validation_complete

my code is as follows

html:

```
   <form class="form inline d-flex justify-content-center" action="contact.php" method="POST" role="form">
             <br style="clear:both">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="control" id="first_name" name="first_name" placeholder="First Name" required>
                <span class="error">* <?php echo $nameErr;?></span>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required>
                <span class="error">* <?php echo $emailErr;?></span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="control" id="last_name" name="last_name" placeholder="Last Name" required>
                <span class="error">* <?php echo $nameErr;?></span>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="control" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Phone" required>
                <span class="error">* <?php echo $phoneErr;?></span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12">
              <div class="form-group">
                <textarea name="message" class="control" id="message" placeholder="What's on your mind?" rows="3"></textarea>
              </div>
              <button type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">SEND</button>
          </form>
```

php:

```
<?php

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

    $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
    $last_name  = $_POST['last_name'];
    $email      = $_POST['email'];
    $phone      = $_POST['phone'];
    $message    = $_POST['message'];

    if (empty($first_name)) {
        $nameErr = "First name is required";
    } else {
        $first_name = check_input($first_name);
        // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$first_name)) {
            $error = "Only letters and white space allowed";
        } else {
            $pass += 1;
        }
    }

    if (empty($last_name)) {
        $nameErr = "Last name is required";
    } else {
        $last_name = check_input($last_name);
        // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$last_name)) {
            $error = "Only letters and white space allowed";
        }else {
            $pass += 1;
        }
    }

    if (empty($email)) {
        $emailErr = "Email is required";
    } else {
        $email = check_input($email);
        // check if e-mail address is well-formed
        if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $error = "Invalid email format";
        }else {
            $pass += 1;
        }
    }

    if (empty($phone)) {
        $phoneErr = "Phone number is required";
    } else {
        $phone = check_input($phone);

        if (!preg_match("'^(([\+]([\d]{2,}))([0-9\.\-\/\s]{5,})|([0-9\.\-\/\s]{5,}))*$'",$phone)) {
            $error = "Invalid Phone Number";
        }else {
            $pass += 1;
        }
    }

    if (empty($message)) {
        $error = "Message  cannot be blank";
    } else {
        $message = check_input($message);
        $pass += 1;
    }
}

$email_from =' Client, llc';
$email_subject = 'New Message From A Guest';
$email_body = "Name: $first_name $last_name\n".
              "Email: $email\n".
              "Phone: $phone\n".
              "Message: $message.\n";
$to ="me@work.com";
$headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email \r\n";

if (!isset($error) && $pass == '5'){
    mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
    header("location: thanks.html");
} else {
    echo $error;
}

// purge the session after it is displayed
unset($error);

function check_input($data) {
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
}
?>
```

I dont think the phone check is working properly either but I can try a different preg_match. I just need to get this to work right.

Comment: NOTE: `$pass += 1;` only works if you first initialise `$pass` to a value... normally zero

Comment: I am sure I have seen this code in another question a few minutes ago????

Comment: `$error` is a scalar. If you want to add error messages to `$error` so all found errors show up you would have to use `$error = '';` then `$error .= 'first error';` then `$error .= 'second error';`

Comment: @RiggsFolly, it does look a lot like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51143984/form-validation-issues-serverside-code-is-not-validating), doesn't it.

Comment: The wwwfools example seems to work quite nicely, so we have to assume you have not copied it very well, but I am not going to work through and find the mistakes

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting the value that is in $error everytime an error occurs. You need to append the new error messages to the existing error. Also if you want to have the error messages appear next to the inputs then you need to put the error message in the appropriate error variables.

Update the id for last name error in your html:

```
 <form class="form inline d-flex justify-content-center" action="contact.php" method="POST" role="form">
             <br style="clear:both">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="control" id="first_name" name="first_name" placeholder="First Name" required>
                <span class="error">* <?php echo $nameErr;?></span>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required>
                <span class="error">* <?php echo $emailErr;?></span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="control" id="last_name" name="last_name" placeholder="Last Name" required>
                <span class="error">* <?php echo $nameErr2;?></span>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="control" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Phone" required>
                <span class="error">* <?php echo $phoneErr;?></span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12">
              <div class="form-group">
                <textarea name="message" class="control" id="message" placeholder="What's on your mind?" rows="3"></textarea>
              </div>
              <button type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">SEND</button>
          </form>
```

Try this for your PHP:

```
<?php

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

    $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
    $last_name  = $_POST['last_name'];
    $email      = $_POST['email'];
    $phone      = $_POST['phone'];
    $message    = $_POST['message'];
    $error = ''; //init error to empty string
    $pass = 0; // init pass to 0;

    if (empty($first_name)) {
        $nameErr = "First name is required";
    } else {
        $first_name = check_input($first_name);
        // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$first_name)) {
            $nameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed";
            $error.='<p>'.$nameErr.'</p>';

        } else {
            $pass += 1;
        }
    }

    if (empty($last_name)) {
        $nameErr2 = "Last name is required";
    } else {
        $last_name = check_input($last_name);
        // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$last_name)) {
            $nameErr2 = "Only letters and white space allowed";
            $error.='<p>'.$nameErr2.'</p>';
        }else {
            $pass += 1;
        }
    }

    if (empty($email)) {
        $emailErr = "Email is required";
    } else {
        $email = check_input($email);
        // check if e-mail address is well-formed
        if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $emailErr = "Invalid email format";
            $error.='<p>'.$emailErr.'</p>';
        }else {
            $pass += 1;
        }
    }

    if (empty($phone)) {
        $phoneErr = "Phone number is required";
    } else {
        $phone = check_input($phone);

        if (!preg_match("'^(([\+]([\d]{2,}))([0-9\.\-\/\s]{5,})|([0-9\.\-\/\s]{5,}))*$'",$phone)) {
            $phoneErr = "Invalid Phone Number";
            $error.='<p>'.$phoneErr.'</p>';
        }else {
            $pass += 1;
        }
    }

    if (empty($message)) {
        $msgErr = "Message  cannot be blank";
        $error.='<p>'.$msgErr.'</p>';
    } else {
        $message = check_input($message);
        $pass += 1;
    }
}

$email_from =' Client, llc';
$email_subject = 'New Message From A Guest';
$email_body = "Name: $first_name $last_name\n".
              "Email: $email\n".
              "Phone: $phone\n".
              "Message: $message.\n";
$to ="me@work.com";
$headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email \r\n";

if ($error == '' && $pass == '5'){
    mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
    header("location: thanks.html");
} else {
    echo $error;
}

// purge the session after it is displayed
unset($error);

function check_input($data) {
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
}
?>
```